# Unix STREAMS vs Standard Streams

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Can somebody explain the differences? Both are called "streams", however, their function seem to be quite different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Stream (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing))

Simply a sequence of data elements accessed one at a time. Different from batch data which is processed a batch at a time.

[Standard Streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)

The Standard Streams `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are available to all programs. They abstract away the physical I/O layer. You can consider each as a character or byte stream.

[Unix STREAMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STREAMS)

A native framework used to implement device drivers, network protocols, and inter-process communication. It is part of the Unix System V kernel. It is not a part of Linux. Linux has Pipes and FIFOs (Named Pipes) for inter-process communication.

Comment: You list Wikipedia, but this can just be seen as a hint that the term `streams` is used for various purposes. Also note that in the term `standard streams` the term `standard` is no more than an adjectiv to the term `streams`